# Looking to identify shopify/ecommerce website

Tags: python, web-scraping, e-commerce

Hi I am making a webscraping tool to parse website and determine if they are ecommerce website (contain signs of shopify, magento, etc.) I am feeding in URLs from a csv file. I want to look at the header to find the word this piece of html or something similar.

example from https://www.thecriticalslidesociety.com/

Right now I can solo of the head information but when I try to find that string of html, I don't get anything.

Can someone guide me to what I should do next.

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import re

with open('URL.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    with open('Approval.csv', 'w') as Approval_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(Approval_file, delimiter='_')

    next(csv_reader)
    for line in csv_reader:
        my_URL = line[0]
        Uclient = uReq(my_URL)

        page_html = Uclient.read()

        web_header={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0(Macintosh;IntelMacOSX10_13_2)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,likeGecko)Chrome/63.0.3239.132Safari/537.36'}

        Uclient.close()

        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

        search = page_soup.find("head")
```

Comment: "but when I try to find that string of html, I don't get anything" - What does this mean? What did you expect to find? And what did you find instead?

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://example.com/"
html = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
search = soup.find("head")

print(search)
```

Outputs the `<head>` tag:

```html
<head>
<title>Example Domain</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>
```